# rosjava groovy install help

Tags: ros-groovy, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all

Am looking to install ROS java and have been going through the external documentation here http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html

However it is for older versions of ROS that do not use catkin. Is there anything different I need to do in order to correctly install ROSJava into my catkin workspace?

Also "rosws merge [http://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/.rosinstall"](http://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/.rosinstall%22) is giving me a 404 error and using the links from "https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core" are giving me a 406 Not acceptable error.

Any help from someone who has installed ROSJava on Groovy?

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61782/rosjava-groovy-install-help/) by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2013-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosjava` [has just been catkinized](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/commit/b2bcbbe14aaadbb1a81a07902ea7fd643fa2c63e) in source repo, although I haven't tried it out. You may want to try it out and feedback should be appreciated.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2013-04-29**:
ahh excellent, thank you! Will experiment with it today and will give feedback when I can :D Thanks heaps

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2013-04-29**:
Ok, have downloaded and have rosjava_core in "~/catkin_ws/src/rosjava_core".

Running catkin_make in "~/catkin_ws" however is giving build error "Execution failed for task ':rosjava_test:compileJava'? Can't find a solution, but appears to have been reported at least previosuly

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2013-04-30**:
Feedback so far: When running either "catkin_make" or "./gradlew install" rosjava is unable to find rosjava_test package. I put a report on the git stie here https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/issues/156

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2013-05-07**:
Can you roscd to test_ros? Is it in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2013-05-08**:
will test that tomorrow, I know I can roscd in rosjava_core quite happily. The test_ros "pakcage" is stored within a subdirectory of rosjava_core. Would assume it would be able to see it, but will check tomorrow, cause you are probably right

**Comment by [mbforbes](https://answers.ros.org/users/15401/mbforbes/) on 2014-05-01**:
@HenryW I know this is a year later, but did you have any success? I'm also trying to use rosjava with Groovy and am hitting the `package test_ros does not exist` error when I try to build.

edit: NVM, using wstool then building worked, strange..